# decompose a 3-by-3 matrix into a simpler form

Tags: matrices

The matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-(a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3) & a_2 b_1 & a_3 b_1 \\
 a_1 b_2 & -(a_1 b_1 + a_3 b_3)  & a_3 b_2 \\
 a_1 b_3 & a_2 b_3 & -(a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
shows some pattern.

Can we decompose it into a multiplication of two simpler matrices, or other simpler forms?

Comment: Set $a =(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $b=(b_1, b_2, b_3)$. Then look at $a^T b$ and $a b^T$.

Comment: thanks! it's getting closer...

Comment: I arrive at $b^T a - (a\cdot b) I $